ShowToastEvent not working
It's getting into this code but the toast event doesn't appear on the screen:
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAvailableProperties from '@salesforce/apex/PropertyController.getAvailableProperties';
import getAvailableBookingSlots from '@salesforce/apex/PropertyController.getAvailableBookingSlots';
import createBooking from '@salesforce/apex/PropertyController.createBooking';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class PropertyBooking extends LightningElement {
    @track selectedProperty;
    @track selectedSlot;
    @track error;
    @track slots = [];

    @wire(getAvailableProperties) properties;

    @wire(getAvailableBookingSlots, { propertyId: '$selectedProperty' })
    wiredSlots({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            //this.slots = data;
            for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                this.slots[i] = data[i].start + ' to ' + data[i].end;
            }
            //console.log('this.slots ------- ', JSON.stringify(this.slots));
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.slots = [];
        }
    }

    get propertyOptions() {
        return this.properties.data ? this.properties.data.map(property => {
            return { label: property.Name, value: property.Id };
        }) : [];
    }

    handlePropertyChange(event) {
        this.selectedProperty = event.detail.value;
        this.selectedSlot = null; // Reset selected slot when changing property
    }

    handleSlotSelection(event) {
        this.selectedSlot = event.target.dataset.slot;
        console.log('selectedSlot --- ', this.selectedSlot);
        this.handleBooking();
    }

    handleShowToast() {
        console.log('here');
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Get Help',
            message:
                'Salesforce documentation is available in the app. Click ? in the upper-right corner.',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    handleBooking() {
        if (this.selectedProperty && this.selectedSlot) {
            const slot = this.slots[parseInt(this.selectedSlot)];
            console.log('slots[slot] --- ', JSON.stringify(this.slots[this.selectedSlot]));
            console.log('slots.length--- ', JSON.stringify(this.slots.length));

            
            const startDate = new Date(slot.slice(0, 10));
            const endDate = new Date(slot.slice(14, slot.length));

            createBooking({ propertyId: this.selectedProperty, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate })
                .then(result => {
                    console.log('1111111111111111', result);
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Booking Status',
                            message: result,
                            variant: result.includes('successfully') ? 'success' : 'error',
                        })
                    );
                    console.log('222222222222222');
                    if (result.includes('successfully')) {
                        console.log('33333333333333333333');
                        // Refresh the available properties and slots
                        return refreshApex(this.properties) && refreshApex(this.wiredSlots);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Error creating booking',
                            message: error.body.message,
                            variant: 'error',
                        })
                    );
                });
        } else {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Missing Information',
                    message: 'Please select a property and a date range to book.',
                    variant: 'warning',
                })
            );
        }
    }
}


ShowToastEvent is only supported in some environments. Where are you trying to show this toast?

Really? I'm working in a scratch org

Did you import "ShowToastEvent" ?
Like this: import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

Yes.
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

And the LWC is on an experience cloud page if that matters

It does matter - that is what sfdcfox meant. Is it an Aura or LWR digital experience? They work in Aura but not LWR, IIRC.

You can refer to this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/353382/can-showtoast-be-utilized-in-lwr-site-experience-cloud
